# Как скачать шрифт с Google Fonts (cyrillic)?

Tags: шрифты, google-fonts

Пытаюсь вот загрузить шрифт Roboto. По идее он поддерживает кириллицу, а смотрю в Character Set — шрифт не имеет кириллических символов.

При сборке шрифта я указываю латиницу и кириллицу, через CDN наверняка загружается нормальный шрифт, но мне нужно разместить шрифт у себя.

Как или где настраивается набор символов шрифта Google Fonts, при скачивании коллекции?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cайт, где можно скачать гугл шрифт

https://github.com/google/fonts/tree/master/apache

или здесь

http://www.fontsquirrel.com/fonts/roboto

В настройках выбрать **Expert**

**Subsetting:** --> **Custom Subsetting...**

отметить необходимо checkbox **Cyrillic**

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[Вот более подробно описано](http://css-live.ru/faq/ne-standartnye-shrifty-v-web-vmeste-s-fontsquirrel.html)

Answer (score 1):

Самые свежие версии шрифтов Google Fonts можно скачать на github
https://github.com/google/fonts/tree/master/apache/roboto